# Regarding extraterrestrial beings

Tags: practical-islam, alien

It seems kind of weird to me that humans could be the only intelligent beings in this universe. We are so small. Does Allah say that aliens exist? Are there any hadiths or verses in the Quran that might hint that they do?

Comment: Why don't you check the site first for existing answers. For example by clicking on the tag [tag:alien].

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing explicitly mentioned, however the Qur'ān does mention that there are those things created that we do not know of.